# switch between views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have two views named it has portrait and landscape, on rotation i want to switch the views.But when on load it works fine but on rotation its  not working.please tel me to fix this problem

```
 -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
    {
        self.view = self.portrait;    
    }
    else
    {
        self.view = self.landscape;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the supported interface orientations?

Comment: And next time, please follow proper code indentation guidelines when putting code here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ Richard J. Ross III ya i have

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

function in your MainViewController class, to make autorotation work. Look it up in the reference: [Reference Documentation on ViewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You could simply say (to support all orientations):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: that method is added as well.

Comment: in the above code its not there..but in my project i have added the above method

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your supported orientations set in your project settings, you can just do this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Adding this will give the view controller permission to actually effect the changes you have in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Also, try using this code to switch between views:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
    duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [UIView transitionFromView:self.view
                        toView:self.portrait
                      duration:0.7 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft   
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        //do something when done with animation
                      }]; 
    } else {
        [UIView transitionFromView:self.view
                        toView:self.landscape
                      duration:0.7 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft   
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        //do something when done with animation
                      }];
    }
}
```